# Two different URLs, One site

Tags: php

How can I have the same WordPress site run on two different URLs?

For example, [www.brand1.com](http://www.brand1.com) and [www.brand2.com](http://www.brand2.com). They have the SAME content, just some different graphics or ads (which could be handled in javascipt?).

I don't think multisite is what I need because that runs two different sites on the same instance of WordPress. What I need is to run the same site twice (with shared SQL and php) but give each a slightly different "look" or "branding".

I'm not sure if URL rewriting will work. The examples I've seen just rewrite the path (after the server part of the url).

TIA

Comment: You've pretty much described a multisite with this line: "The same site but with a different branding" I would suggest using a multisite approach and then using domain mapping to achieve the unique domains for subsites.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look at my question. However, I don't think multisite will work: I have two sites with completely different URL domains. For example www.brand1.com and www.brand2.com. From what I could tell, multisite would only work if the domains were common: brand1.domain.com and brand2.domain.com.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hello - Multisite will work with different domains.  This article has a fairly good explanation of how to set it up: https://krystal.uk/blog/post/wordpress-multisite-different-domains    If you have a good managed WordPress hosting plan the web host can help set up multisite for you.  (WPEngine or FlyWheel for example)